# How should one advertise a program if it doesn't lead to jobs?

Tags: job-search, university, south-east-asia

(Asking this since similar themes have come up in a conversation with a friend)

So-and-so physics department has decided to start teaching more astrophysics classes, because they need more students. Astronomy with all its pretty pictures is supposed to attract students - certainly the general education classes that cater to students fulfilling their breadth requirements are very popular. The idea is to add several more astrophysics courses and offer undergraduates who take all of them a "concentration in Astrophysics", so their degrees say "Bachelor of Physics with concentration in Astrophysics".

The problem: in that particular city - or country, even - nobody is looking for astrophysics graduates. In fact after being subscribed to "astronomy" and "astrophysics" job advertisements for more than a year, I've only seen like two jobs with those keywords, and one of them had nothing to do with astronomy or astrophysics. One could still get a job leveraging the fact that astrophysics is "sort of" physics which is a quantitative discipline that teaches its graduates to think logically yada yada blah blah. But at that point, the astrophysics concentration seems pretty pointless.

How do you advertise a program knowing that its graduates will not be able to find jobs in that topic? What is a good response to "what do your graduates do after graduating?"

Comment: I think it might help if you mention what country, as the cultural expectations of the relationship between education and employment is different in different countries.  For example, in the US, especially at elite institutions, investment banks and consulting companies will hire smart graduates without much regard to what subject they have concentrated in, whereas it seems a similar German company would hire only economics/finance/business students.

Comment: I imagine this is a common problem. What do other departments in the same university do?

Comment: As a meta comment - I don't think that the purpose of academia in general is creating jobs. If schools were to become vocational then teaching astrophysics (or physics in general) is a bad idea. Astrophysics is at the very least teaching its students some 'useful' skills like algebra/probability/basic programming, as opposed to some humanities subjects.

Comment: Why is the search space for jobs from that university only that city or country? I assume this isn't the US or other large country as I can't imagine there have been no astro* jobs posted in the past two years

Comment: I tagged by region, and I suspect conventions are similar across the region.

Comment: @YairZick yes but there are physics job, including some research positions (although those tend to be applied in nature). Usually the description would say "Degree in a quantitative discipline, such as physics, math, ___". Since astrophysics is never listed, it makes it feel like a concentration in this topic is useless.

Comment: @AzorAhai searching anywhere else might involve emigrating, which is never easy since it involves visas (especially if one has a partner or children). Even moving to a different city in the same country is not trivial, either.

Comment: Your question isn't clear on some key questions: did the program add an astrophysics degree?  And is it an undergraduate or graduate program?

Comment: @DavidKetcheson undergraduate program, adds astrophysics concentration only (the department doesn't have enough astronomers to add a full-fledged astrophysics degree).

Comment: @Allure Please add that important information to your question.  You should probably explain precisely what a "concentration" is, since I guess that's what you're advertising.

Comment: Please keep discussion on-topic and related to clarifying issues about the question. "Meta comments" don't belong here, take them to [chat].

Comment: @Allure For sure. But since I'm so used to reading these with a US or EU mindset, it wasn't clear. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Wait, is this mine University? They had similar problem. If you can connect to meteorology. Problem is aolved

Answer (score 2):

If the basic degree is still Physics with a bit of astro tacked on I don't see the problem. Even pure Astrophysics degrees usually follow all the core physics classes before specialising.

For example, my Astrophysics degree is probably about 75% identical to my pure Physics counterparts, so as long as students make potential employers aware of this, they should be just as employable as a Physics graduate.

As a side note, perhaps students should be encouraged to study what they actually find interesting, not what will get them a job. They are likely to perform better if they enjoy the material, and with better grades and an enthusiasm for their degree, the jobs will come.

Comment: You don't find this to be a problem? That's surprising (and distressing) - see e.g. https://www.news.com.au/finance/work/hapless-graduates-sue-their-former-universities-in-shockingly-high-numbers/news-story/6f5a7be7093804775034301bacb07a23

Comment: Also an astrophysics concentration would teach subjects such as stellar nucleosynthesis, planetary science, cosmology, galaxy dynamics ... the opportunity cost of taking these classes would be missing out on topics like biophysics, surface science and material science, which could potentially be relevant (as mentioned there are some research positions requiring physics which tend to be applied - i.e. use these topics). One can still get a non-research position, but it would still be missing out on an option.

Comment: I don't see this to be a problem. I and all my friends with astrophysics degrees are doing just fine even though we never studied biophysics... No matter what degree you choose you have to make some sacrifices, for example, we didn't learn creative writing, or organic chemistry, or geology, or physiotherapy, or medicine, or....

Comment: But that's because you have a job in astrophysics. If you have to find a job outside of academia, in a situation where nobody is looking for astrophysics, not having taken one of these other topics is going to narrow your options, e.g. searching for "material science" yields pages upon pages of results while "astrophysics" yields one page.

Comment: If the students are adults, that is their decision to make. Besides, I imagine there are far more material scientists than astrophysicists looking for work anyway, so it's not surprising there are proportionally more jobs. Not to mention all the unrelated to physics jobs an astrophysics graduate could do.

Answer (score -1):

Given the variety of some of the jobs that graduates land, the benefit of a science-based degree is the structured thinking/maths skills/theoretical knowledge that are useful to the employer, not necessarily the exact topic studied.

Many of the disciplines have core parts that overlap.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question.

Comment: i seemed to have missed your answer...